# coldfusion check mark all boxes in list

Tags: checkbox, coldfusion

I have a form with a dynamic table. when its submitted for some calculation i need the checkboxes that were origninally checked to be checked again. I do bring back a list of sq_claim_ids thats comma delimmeted #form.number#, I cant figure out the syntax to get coldfusion to loop through the list and check mark each row whos value is in the list. I know I should probably use a cfif tag but i dont know whats the right syntax for the rest of what I need

```
<CFOUTPUT query = "qGetOpenItemsTrans">
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "chkbx" id='#ID#' value="#seq_claim_id#"     onClick="goFurther(this)" unchecked = 0   >
        </TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Inventory_Date#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#seq_claim_id#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Month_Closed#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Amount_Rcvd_by_FRG#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Commission_Amt#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Net_Recovery#</TD>
    </TR>
</CFOUTPUT>

<cfif (form.number) NEQ "">
<cfloop index="i" list="#form.number#" delimiters=",">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Not enough detail.  Are you submitting the form to itself?  In other words, if the form is on abc.cfm does the form tag say action="abc.cfm"?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your checkboxes are named "chkbx" but your description refers to `form.number`, which is not defined anywhere in the code above. Also, it is not clear what the incomplete cfloop code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 3):

Try this concept.

```
<cfset lang_list = "C,C++,Java">
<cfoutput >

<form method="post">
Favorite Programing Language:
<cfloop list="#lang_list#" index="i" >
    <cfif structKeyExists(FORM,"fav") and listFind(FORM.fav,i)>
        <cfset isChecked = "checked">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset isChecked = "">  
    </cfif> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="#i#" #isChecked#>#i#   
</cfloop>   
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Small correction. Do not use `listContains` here because it matches partial strings. So if you checked "C++" (only), both the "C" and "C++" boxes would be checked when the form reloads. Instead use `listFind/FindNoCase`.

Comment: I cant use structkeyexists in this case. I need the cfif to basically say if the value of the check box exists in this comma delimited list , checkmark

Comment: Yes, you can use `StructKeyExists`. It sounds like you are misunderstanding the example and how checkboxes operate. Checkboxes are only submitted IF they are checked. So you may get an error if you just use the field without first verifying it exists. That is the purpose of the structKeyExists code. Verify *something* was checked, *then* use list functions to determine which boxes to re-select.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. since the table already loops i used a cfif tag around it

```
<cfset ischecked = "">
<cfif (form.number) NEQ "">
    <CFOUTPUT query = "qGetOpenItemsTrans">
           <cfif #ListFind(#form.number#, #qGetOpenItemsTrans.seq_claim_id#)# NEQ 0>
           <cfset isChecked = "checked">
           </cfif>
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "chkbx" id='#ID#' value="#seq_claim_id#"     onClick="goFurther(this)" unchecked = 0 #ischecked#   >
        </TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Inventory_Date#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#seq_claim_id#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Month_Closed#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Amount_Rcvd_by_FRG#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Commission_Amt#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Net_Recovery#</TD>
    </TR>
    <cfset ischecked = "">
</CFOUTPUT>



<cfelse>
<CFOUTPUT query = "qGetOpenItemsTrans">
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "chkbx" id='#ID#' value="#seq_claim_id#"     onClick="goFurther(this)" unchecked = 0   >
        </TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Inventory_Date#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#seq_claim_id#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Month_Closed#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Amount_Rcvd_by_FRG#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Commission_Amt#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Net_Recovery#</TD>
    </TR>
</CFOUTPUT>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Good that you got it resolved, and better for coming back and sharing your resolution to try to help other people, but that is difficult to read, and easy to accidentally break. You should do as Deepak suggested and move the last <cfset isChecked = ""> to a <cfelse> within the cfif statement. `<cfif #ListFind(#form.number#, #qGetOpenItemsTrans.seq_claim_id#)# NEQ 0><cfset isChecked = "checked"><cfelse><cfset isChecked = ""></cfif>`.

Comment: You could simplify the above by getting rid of the duplication caused by the if/else. Not sure what `form.number` represents, but the `listFind` code should work regardless of whether that field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Deepak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26304183/3917091).

First, as Leigh said, use `ListFind()` over `ListContains()`. This is important and not just semantics. `#ListContains("42,17,32",4)#` will match and cause the checkbox to be checked. `#ListFind("42,17,32",4)#` will (correctly) not match because no single element equals 4. The potential here could be catastrophic left unchanged. Records could be irrevocably altered or dropped if a user doesn't realize that box was checked mistakenly.

Second, Deepak's answer is otherwise great, but this is a great opportunity to use an inline if statement.

With Cold Fusion 9, or Railo 3.1+, you can use an inline-if statement like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="#i#"
  #(structKeyExists(FORM,"fav") and listfind(FORM.fav,i) ? "checked" : "")#>
```

Inline Ifs in the above format are `#(condition ? expression-if-true : expression-if-false)#`

For older versions of either, you can use the Iif function, though there's a little bit of a stigma attached to IIf.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="3"
  #IIf(structKeyExists(FORM,"fav") and listfind(FORM.fav,i),DE("checked"),"")#>
```

Iif syntax is `#iif(condition, expression-if-true, expression-if-false)#`. However, pass a string, such as "checked"` as above, you have to wrap it in DE(), otherwise Cold Fusion (and Railo) will look for a variable *named* checked.

If you can use CF9's inline ifs over IIf, defnitely do so, unless backwards compatibility is a concern.

Both methods above serve the same purpose as Deepak's answer, with Leigh's `ListFind()` correction, and all would be identical to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="3"
   <cfif (structKeyExists(FORM,"fav") and listfind(FORM.fav,i))>checked</cfif>>
```

Aside from adding some visual bloath, this code works fine, but many html editors auto-formatting features do funky things with that, like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="3"
  <cfif (structKeyExists(FORM,"fav") and listfind(FORM.fav,i))>
    checked
  </cfif>
>
```

Or just break the code completely.

Comment: I have updated my answer with listFind(). But regarding `IIF` I am not sure because many CF Best Practice guide says not to use it.EX: http://www.ipaul.com/2009/08/01/coldfusion-best-practices/

Comment: I don't believe IIf is necessarily a best practice either, I was simply showing how old versions of cf/railo could duplicate it. Have you read? However, I've never seen anything bad about CF9+'s syntax for conditional Ifs. There are a lot of cases where it's inappropriate or not a gain, but I think using it to place a tag attribute is an ideal use. On IIf, however, have you read http://www.bennadel.com/blog/162-coldfusion-iif-vs-cfif.htm? He found IIF and CFIF to be neck and neck and had, like most of us, approached the topic with disdain for IIf. Of course, both articles are years old.

Comment: Yes using `IIF`, makes the code look cleaner and performance also might be the same.I am not sure certainly.